# How to handle and interpolate a dynamic template literal string's format with values in javascript?

Tags: javascript

How to handle and interpolate a dynamic template literal string's format with values that can sometimes contain all 6 variables(maximum) but can contain format with sometimes just 2 variables, sometimes with sometimes just 4 variables. Please note order for the variables can be different.

I get template literal string's format from database for cardLabel property to display. ***I have a deal object and the values will come from that object:
deal={group: 'aaa', Desc: 'abcd' ....etc}***

cardLabel’s dynamic template literal string's format examples:

```js
cardLabel='{Group} {Desc} - {termMonth} Month - {termOdometer} KMs/Miles {DeductibleAmount} {DeductibleType}';

cardLabel='{Desc} - {termMonth} Month - {termOdometer} KMs/Miles';

cardLabel='{Desc} {Group} - {termMonth} Month';

cardLabel='{Group} {Desc} - {termMonth} Month {DeductibleAmount}';
```

Comment: Those aren't template literals, they're oddly formatted strings :). Template literals have dollar signs (`${foo}`) and are delimited by backticks on both ends.

Comment: Are you asking how to replace `{Desc}` with what is stored in a variable `Desc`?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no in-built solution for this in vanilla JavaScript. You need to write helper function for this or use a templating system.

Comment: Yes Zac Anger.They are aren't template literals. I relate this situation to template literals.

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65666055/13762301

Comment: How many variables there are or in what order doesn't matter, just call `.replace("{Desc}", Desc)` on the string, once for each of the six.

Comment: No Chris G. I want to replace variables with their actual values from my deal object and how I should handle the whole situation because the string can contains either 2 or 4 or 6 values and the variables can be in any order.

Comment: I have a deal object and the values will come from that object:
deal={group: 'aaa', Desc: 'abcd' ....etc}

Comment: So what? Again, the order doesn't matter. And calling .replace() with a search term that isn't found will leave the string unchanged. It's really that simple: https://jsfiddle.net/1Ltcknzf/

Comment: In case a `{variable}` in your `cardLabel` template string is not found on the `deal` object, should it be interpolated into en empty string, or left unaltered?

Comment: @KarimAli This simple solution with regex should perfectly suit your needs. https://stackoverflow.com/a/7734771/14967413

Comment: user14967413 : In case a {variable} in your cardLabel template string is not found on the deal object, it should it be left unaltered.

Comment: Thanks Chris G: Your example is exactly what I am looking for. Thanks.